# find best k-means from a list of candidates

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I have an array of size n of points called A, and a candidate array of size O(k)>k called S. I want to find k points in S such that the sum of squared distances from the points of A to their closest point from the k points would be minimized. One way to do it would be to check the cost of any possible k points in S and take the minimum, but that would take O(k^k*n) time, is there any more efficient way to do it?

I need either an optimal solution or a constant approximation.

The reason I need this is that I'm trying to find a constant approximation for the k-means as fast as possible and later use this for a coreset construction (coreset=data minimization while still keeping the cost of any query approximately the same). I was able to show that if we assume that in the optimal clustering each cluster has omega(n/k) points we can create pretty fast a list of size O(k) canidates that contains inside of them a 3-approximation for the k-means, so I was wondering if we can find those k points or a constant approximation for their costs in time which is faster than exhaustive search.

**Example for k=2**
[image]
In this example S is the green dots and A is the red dots. The algorithm should return the 2 circled points from S since they minimize the sum of squared distances from the points of A to their closest point of the 2.

Comment: "and a candidate array of size O(k)>k called S"  I assume you wanted to write something like "K > k" and not "O(k) > k"

Comment: @Stef I meant K>k but also K=O(k).

Comment: @Elliott No, they are high dimensional.

Comment: Your current formulation means that if all the `n` points in A have the same closest point in S, all the `k-1` other points in S and their distances to points in A do not matter, is this correct?

Comment: @tobias_k minimizing sum of square distances is different from minimizing sum of distances. And yes if they all have the same closest point than the other k-1 points are arbitrary.

Comment: Have you actually tried using the famous [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm? Or more precisely, its variant [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids), using points in S for the medoids?

Comment: How big are A and k in practice?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I want it to work for any n and k but assuming n >> k. I've edited to question to explain why I need this.

Comment: If this is high dimensional, why do you think that your choice of points is going to make much difference?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality suggests that it won't.

Comment: @btilly doesn't k-mean clustering still works in high dimentions if n is big enough (n is much bigger than d)?

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array of size `n` of points called `A`, and a candidate array of size `O(k)>k` called `S`. I want to find `k` points in `S` such that the sum of squared distances from the points of `A` to their closest point from the `k` points would be minimized.

It sounds like this could be solved simply by checking the `N` points against the `K` points to find the `k` points in `N` with the smallest squared distance.

Therefore, I'm now fairly sure this is actually finding the `k-nearest neighbors` (K-NN as a computational geometry problem, not the pattern recognition definition) in the `N` points for each point in the `K` points and not actually k-means.

For higher dimensionality, it is often useful to also consider the dimensionality, `D` in the algorithm.

The algorithm mentioned is indeed `O(NDk^2)` then when considering K-NN instead. That can be improved to `O(NDk)` by using Quickselect algorithm on the distances. This allows for checking the list of `N` points against each of the `K` points in `O(N)` to find the nearest `k` points.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Edit:
Seems there is some confusion on quickselect and if it can be used. Here is a `O(DkNlogN)` solution that uses a standard sort `O(NlogN)` instead of quickselect `O(N)`. Though this might be faster in practice and as you can see in most languages it's pretty easy to implement.

```
results = {}
for y in F:
  def distanceSquared(x):
    distance(x,y) # Custom distance for each y

  # First k sorted by distanceSquared
  results[y] = S.sort(key=distanceSquared)[:k]
return results
```

---

Update for new visual

```
# Build up distance sums O(A*N*D)
results = {}
for y in F:
  def distanceSquared(x):
    distance(x,y) # Custom distance for each y

  # Sum of distance squared from y for all points in S
  results[y] = sum(map(distanceSquared, S))

def results_key_value(key):
  results[key]

# First k results sorted by key O(D*AlogA)
results.keys().sort(key=results_key_value)[:k]
```

---

You could approximate by only considering Z random points chosen from the `S` points. Alternatively, you could merge points in `S` if they are close enough together. This could reduce `S` to a much smaller size as long `S` remains about `F^2` or larger in size, it shouldn't affect which points in `F` are chosen too much. Though you would also need to adjust the weight of the points to handle that better. IE: the square distance of a point that represents 10 points is multiplied by 10 to account for it acting as 10 points instead of just 1.

Comment: No, I'm trying to find the best k means from a list of O(k) candidates. It takes (O(k) choose k)*n=O(k^k*n) to check all  the  possible options .

Comment: Ah yes, reading it again, looks like this is actually more KNN than k-means then. Changed my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how KNN helps in this case. KNN gets known labeled clusters and use them to classify an unlabeled data point, it has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do, is given a list S, find a sub list F of size k from S such that the sum of squared distances from the points of some list A to their closest point in F is minimized. This is like finding the best k-means for A but with the constraint that the k-means themselves (I.e. the "centers" of each cluster) has to be a subset of S.

Comment: My apologizes, seems the K-NN Wikipedia does focus a bit too much on a very specific use for K-NN and not enough on the actual "find the K-Nearest Neighbors to a given point" problem. Sounds like you should be good just using the Quickselect answer I provided. Unless you need to repeatedly use different `F` lists to test against the same `N` list, it is basically as good as you can get in terms of Big O notation, and even so it should be better than what you have now unless K is very small indeed (say less than 10 or so). With small enough inputs the fastest algorithm is often the simplist.

Comment: Also K-NN is still valid if you treat the label as one of the points in F list. K-NN is just a algorithm that you need to a apply to each of the points in the `F` list. But yea, quickselect should do the job.

Comment: QuickSelect doesn't help in this case. QuickSelect finds the smallest k values in an array, that's not what I'm looking for... I'm trying to find a sub set F from S such that sum_{a\in A}{min_{b\in F}dist^2(a,b)} is minimized. Maybe I didn't explained myself good enough in the question.

Comment: No you did, you just aren't following me as perhaps I'm not being explict enough. Quickselect finds the smallest k values in an array, yes. However, the value that quickselect uses doesn't _have_ to be the actual value of the array element. So it is typically `f(x) = x`. But you, could instead define it as `f(x) = distance^2(x,y)` where `x` is in S and `y` is in `F`. There is no need to consider the sum if you are using the `k` points in `S` with the smallest `distance^2` to `y` in `F`, as by definition, they will have the smallest possible sum. Added a simple sort based solution in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand, it seems to me like you're suggesting to find the closest k points to each point how would that help? Also I'm trying to find F so how can I calculate distance^2(x y). S has more than k points and I'm trying to find only k that would minimize the sum, I have to consider the sum. Also the distance from the points of S to F doesn't matter, what's matter is the distances from A to F.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking then, perhaps a visual would help?

Comment: I added a visual example

Comment: Ah so you are using the sum of the dist^2 for _all_ of the points in S to the `F` points, then find the smallest `k` `F` points. IE: Find the sum dist^2 from each `F` point to all `S` points. Then you want the `k` smallest of those sums. Seems like it's `O(SFD)` then and not much you can optimize since you have to calculate the distances for t least every S-F point pair which is `O(SF)`. Added an updated algorithm for it. Also added optimization ideas if `SF` is still a bit too slow. Though running the optimization my be even slower.